# Safari Hero Carousel Fix

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, safari, zurb-foundation

I am working on a Wordpress blog `theelementmag.com`. It works perfectly in every other browser but Safari. In Safari the images in the carousel at the top are not inline and the post images on the bottom are all different sizes. Please help me figure out how I can fix the Safari issue. I use `http://www.paulwelsh.info/jquery-plugins/hero-carousel/` and Foundation 5. Any pointers will be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least one javascript error that is probably breaking the carousel. Start with learning to use the developer tools in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) (or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)) or [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what javascript is loading on your site and the errors.

Comment: I've fixed that javascript issue but that hasn't fixed the problem.